# Creating a dynamic object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, loops

I'm trying to understand why my code isn't working. this is a piece of code that I'm creating for a game in canvas. I want to dynamically create an object to capture the radius, x and y coordinates. Eventually this will become a setInterval functon If i can get the console.log to produce I'll be good.

```
var i;
var circles = {};
for (i = 0; i>10; i++){
  circles[i]= {
    d:Math.floor(Math.random()*50),
    x:Math.floor(Math.random()*500),
    y:Math.floor(Math.random()*500)
    };
    console.log(circles[i].d, circles[i].x, circles[i].x);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i>10; i++){
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
```